# Whoops! There was a ...previewing this pdf document android

Tags: android, pdf

My application has a list of pdf inside listview. The pdf is viewed inside the application using a webview that open a Google Docs sheet. It works fine for the first opened PDF, but 
when going back and opening another PDF I got the error `"whoops! There was a problem previewing this document"`. Is there some kind of limitation on opening PDF using google sheet. If so, how can I get full rights to open any PDF I want. can someone help please. Here is my code.

```
    //---you need this to prevent the webview from
    // launching another browser when a url
    // redirection occurs---
    wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    wv.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + SharepreferenceController.getPrefSavePdfInfo());
```

Comment: Seeing this same issue this morning on my application. Wondering if Google is finally updating their platform.

Comment: it is not yet updated, but is there another method to load url with pdf content inside the application

Comment: Having a similar issue.  A Google update is my bet also.

Comment: thanks you but it is not open source.  I downloaded the pdf and load it with a third party app from my sd card.  It works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the Version/Compatibility of the PDF. This worked for me.

Edit: I believe it is more of a size issue. When I changed the Version (from Acrobat 9.0 to 10.0) I had also optimized the PDF making it a smaller file. My larger files of the same Version still do not work.

Comment: You were enable to load more than one pdf ?

Comment: Can you specify to what Version of PDF should be enabled for Viewing a document?

Comment: The same pdf is working when viewed from Chrome !! I am still trying to find a solution this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. What solved it for me was clearing the `WebView` cache before trying to load another PDF.

```
WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + url);
```

Comment: Thanks but bigger pdf won't display