# Large PDF file from URL does not rendering in android

Tags: android, pdf, webview, pdfview

PDF from url has 118 pages and more and size of 60MB or more. I have load url in webview like this.

```
    val webSettings = wv.settings
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    wv.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    wv.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17_FlightPlan.pdf")
```

but webview not loading file and showing below message

[image]

how to load big size of pdf file url in webview without download file

Comment: Not `118`, It has **618 pages**. Its not too large, just *389kb*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26864593/1318946